# CORS filter vs WebMvcConfigurer.addCorsMappings

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

What the difference of `cors()` filter in `configure` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class and create bean of `WebMvcConfigurer` and override `addCorsMappings` method? When we use of which? Can anyone explain it?

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        }
    };
}
```

vs

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(this.jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link will clarify you some doubts: https://developpaper.com/whats-the-difference-between-so-many-cors-configurations-in-spring/

Answer (score 9):

**Spring Web MVC**

[`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) is part of the [Spring Web MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc) library. Configuring CORS with `addCorsMappings` adds CORS to all URLs which are handled by Spring Web MVC, see [1.7.2. Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-processing):

> Spring MVC `HandlerMapping` implementations provide built-in support for CORS. After successfully mapping a request to a handler, `HandlerMapping` implementations check the CORS configuration for the given request and handler and take further actions.

(For fine-grained CORS configuration, you can use [`@CrossOrigin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-controller).)

You have to use it, if no Spring Security is used (non secured applications) or not all Spring Web MVC URLs are handled by Spring Security (some ULRs are unsecured).

You can't use it for non Spring Web MVC URLs like JSF, Servlet, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, ...

**Spring Security**

[`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)  is part of the [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/) library. Configuring CORS with [`cors()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--) adds CORS to all URLs which are handled by Spring Security, see [15.8. CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors):

> Spring Framework provides first class support for CORS. CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the `JSESSIONID`). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.
>
> The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the `CorsFilter`.

You have to use it, if you use Spring Security.

If you are using Spring Web MVC and Spring Security together you can share the configuration, see [15.8. CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors):

> If you are using Spring MVC’s CORS support, you can omit specifying the `CorsConfigurationSource` and Spring Security will leverage the CORS configuration provided to Spring MVC.